# What is a good File Manager for a .NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, .net, file-browser

I need a File Manager for C#/.NET in my web application (similar to the old one in Telerik, but I'll avoid Telerik right now).

I need it because the user should browse folder, enter the folder, e select "file". I just need this behaviour.

Found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13097/An-quot-Explorer-Style-quot-TreeView-Control), but I don't know how good it is! What can you suggest to me?

Comment: As a user I prefer to use standard widgets with well-known behavior. As a developer I use the built-in dialogs MS shipped in WinForms and WPF for file selection.

Comment: Browse folder, select file? That sounds like a job for... OpenFileDialog!

Comment: Web application! I need just to open folder and select file, nothing more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser) great example at CodeProject.

If you are willing to purchase a commercial product take a look even at : [JoHer](http://www.joher.com/dotfxp_control_screenshots.shtml) and [Heapar .NET File Explorer Control](http://www.heapar.com/products.php?id=8) .

**UPDATE**
For Web Applications :

Take a look at  : [IZWebFileManager](https://github.com/manishma/IZWebFileManager/) .

*This question could be a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083596/recommendations-for-net-web-based-file-manager-editor) .*

Comment: But this is not for a web application :O

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. You should specify the target platform in your question ...

Comment: that IZWebFileManager rocks, but it is not free :(

Comment: oh now, well, it is also free...under GPL! :) Dunno where to put the DLLS, I need to figure it out...